# How can I measure the frequency which is good enough take out the data from RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I have RabbitMQ running on a server and there's some script which inserts data into it. I know the approximate frequency in which the data is inserted, but it's not only approximate, it can also vary quite a lot.

- How can I know how often does another script have to take the data out of RabbitMQ?
- What will happen if the 2nd script take the data out of RabbitMQ slower than needed?
- How can I measure whether or not the frequency is good enough?

Comment: The simplest single metric available is queue size. If the queue starts growing, you're not processing fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I know how often does another script have to take the data out of RabbitMQ?

You should consume messages from the queue at a rate greater than or equal to the rate they are published.  RabbitMQ reports publish rates; however, you will want to get a reasonable estimate from load testing your application.

> What will happen if the 2nd script take the data out of RabbitMQ slower than needed?

In the short term, the number of messages in the queue will increase, as will processing time (think about what happens when more people get in line for Space Mountain at Disney).  In the long term, the system will be unstable because the queue will increase without bound, eventually resulting in a failure of the queue, as well as other practical consequences (think of this as the case where Space Mountain is broken down, but people are still allowed to enter the queue line).

> How can I measure whether or not the frequency is good enough?

From an information only perspective, you can monitor the queue yourself using the RabbitMQ management plugin. If you need automated processes to spawn up additional workers, you'll have to integrate those processes into the RabbitMQ management API. How to do this is the subject of a number of how-to articles.